# Installing Magento automatically

Tags: magento

I'm thinking about installing magento in automatical way. I suppose that I need to create some script or something... but I guess I'm not first person whom need it. So do you know about any good resource or solution how to it? It would work in Windows and Linux OS. Thanks. Jaro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably others out there but here is a quick and dirty script I use form time to time to install Magento checkout my svn repo and initialise modman.  It could be extended to create database if required etc, but it works fine for me as is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Required Script Variables
DB_NAME=
DB_USER=
DB_HOST=
DB_PASS=
URL=
MAGENTO_VERSION="1.7.0.0"
ADMIN_FIRSTNAME=
ADMIN_SURNAME=
ADMIN_EMAIL=
ADMIN_USER=
ADMIN_PASS=
SVN_REPO=


# Download and install Magento
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/$MAGENTO_VERSION/magento-$MAGENTO_VERSION.tar.gz

printf "\n\nUnpacking and preparing to install Magento...\n" 

tar -zxvf magento-$MAGENTO_VERSION.tar.gz
mv magento/* magento/.htaccess .
chmod -R o+w media var
chmod o+w app/etc
rm -rf downloader/pearlib/cache/* downloader/pearlib/download/*
rm -rf magento/ magento-$MAGENTO_VERSION.tar.gz

printf "\n\nInstalling Magento...\n"

/usr/local/bin/php -f install.php -- \
    --license_agreement_accepted "yes" \
    --locale "en_GB" \
    --timezone "Europe/London" \
    --default_currency "GBP" \
    --db_host "$DB_HOST" \
    --db_name "$DB_NAME" \
    --db_user "$DB_USER" \
    --db_pass "$DB_PASS" \
    --url "$URL" \
    --use_rewrites "yes" \
    --use_secure "no" \
    --secure_base_url "" \
    --use_secure_admin "no" \
    --skip_url_validation "yes" \
    --admin_firstname "$ADMIN_FIRSTNAME" \
    --admin_lastname "$ADMIN_SURNAME" \
    --admin_email "$ADMIN_EMAIL" \
    --admin_username "$ADMIN_USER" \
    --admin_password "$ADMIN_PASS"


# Setup svn and modman
modman init
mkdir .modman/modules
svn co $SVN_REPO .modman/modules
modman update-all
```